# How to pass data from Javascript to Swift within a WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to pass data from my sites Javascript to my app, written in Swift.

**Javascript:**

```
var messgeToPost = {
     "username": "testing123"
};
window.webkit.messageHandlers.loginSuccess.postMessage(messgeToPost);
```

**Swift:**

```
var webConfig:WKWebViewConfiguration {
    get {
        var webCfg:WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        var userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()

        userController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "loginSuccess")

        webCfg.userContentController = userController;

        return webCfg;
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
     var userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
     userController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "loginSuccess")
     webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame,
        configuration: webConfig)
     webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLPath)!))
}

func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if let messageBody:NSDictionary = message.body as? NSDictionary {
        let password:String = messageBody["password"] as! String

        print(password)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `print(password)` is never called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is no `password` attribute in the `messgeToPost` object.

Answer (score 5):

```
var messgeToPost = {
     "username": "testing123",
     "password": "password"
};
```

forgot to add password